# How to change output directory of a meson subproject?

Tags: c++, meson-build

Here is my `meson.build`:

```
project('Adventum', 'cpp', version : '0.1.0', license : '', default_options : ['cpp_std=c++2a'])

glfw = subproject('glfw').get_variable('glfw_dep')
vulkan = dependency('vulkan')   

sources = ['src/main.cpp', 'src/render/window.cpp']

exe = executable('Adventum', sources, include_directories : 'src', dependencies : [glfw, vulkan])
```

and here is my 'subproject" (wrap):

```
[wrap-git]
url = https://github.com/henry4k/glfw-meson.git
revision = head
```

I'm using the GLFW library but I have to pull from a third-party fork that supports meson. This all works fine, and meson successfully downloads and builds the GLFW fork, but even though meson should clearly know that my project depends on the GLFW library it doesn't actually place the GLFW binaries alongside my projects executable, so it builds the dependency but my program cannot run because it doesn't find the necessary binaries.

Is there something I must specify in my `meson.build` for it to automatically place the binaries next to my executeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do not specify a directory name or a `[provide]` section with `dependency_names`, the file name of the `.wrap` will determine how the subproject is called.
So, in case your wrap file was called `glfw-meson.wrap` your subproject could be referenced with `glfw-meson` only.

Better practice is to specify `directory`:

```
[wrap-git]
directory = glfw
url = https://github.com/henry4k/glfw-meson.git
revision = head
```

or `dependency_names`:

```
[wrap-git]
url = https://github.com/henry4k/glfw-meson.git
revision = head

[provide]
dependency_names = glfw
```

Then, you should be able to call `subproject('glfw')`